# Faster way of hiding rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a faster, or more practical way of hiding rows in all sheets that have a zero value in column A? I have set up multiple macros to hide the rows, but this takes about 50-70 secs to complete any faster way?

```
Sub Macro14()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Main").Range("A200:A500")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Main").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Main").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro15()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Elkhart East").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Elkhart East").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Elkhart East").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro16()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Tennessee").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Tennessee").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Tennessee").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro17()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Alabama").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Alabama").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Alabama").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro18()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("North Carolina").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("North Carolina").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("North Carolina").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro19()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Pennsylvania").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Pennsylvania").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Pennsylvania").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro20()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Texas").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("Texas").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("Texas").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro21()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("West Coast").Range("A50:A300")
        If c.value = 0 Then
            Sheets("West Coast").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("West Coast").Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use autofilter or array.

Comment: @brucewayne now the cells are not blank they have a zero value because they reference another sheet

Comment: (I deleted my answer, I misread your question)

Comment: @findwindow I want this to be done using a macro, because the macros are run through a command button

Comment: You can write a macro for autofilter or array ^_^; Edit: also if those are all the sheets in your workbook, consider `for each ws in thisworkbook`

Comment: @findwindow any suggestions?

Comment: You can start by recording one? Or google. Autofilter will be "easier" to understand but array is sexier ~_^ Edit: sexier _and_ faster.

Comment: @Luis 50 secs seems a lot longer for such a short range .

Comment: @newguy It is also hiding rows for multiple sheets maybe that's why

Comment: Why have you written separate macros for each sheets when you can loop over to each of them in a single one ? You can use a simple Select case for selecting range based on sheet name there are just two cases though.

Comment: @newguy sounds like something I should try, could you provide suggestions in how to set up sorry very new to vba

Comment: @newguy because we don't know if that's all the sheets in the book. Edit: obviously, we can build an array to hold only the desired sheets and loop that but that might be beyond OP now ^_^;

Comment: @newguy please see comment below the answer

Comment: @Luis I mentioned using `Select Case` Statement which will take care of that if done right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it in a pretty fast way:

```
Sub test()
  Dim x As Variant, i As Long, j(1) As Long, rngVal As Variant, rnghide As Range, rngshow As Range, sht As Object
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Main", "Elkhart East", "Tennessee", "Alabama", "North Carolina", "Pennsylvania", "Texas", "West Coast"))
    Set rnghide = Nothing
    Set rngshow = Nothing
    If sht.Name = "Main" Then
      j(0) = 200
      j(1) = 500
    Else
      j(0) = 50
      j(1) = 300
    End If
    x = sht.Range("A1:A" & j(1)).Value
    For i = j(0) To j(1)
      If x(i, 1) = 0 Then
        If rnghide Is Nothing Then Set rnghide = sht.Rows(i) Else Set rnghide = Union(rnghide, sht.Rows(i))
      Else
        If rngshow Is Nothing Then Set rngshow = sht.Rows(i) Else Set rngshow = Union(rngshow, sht.Rows(i))
      End If
    Next
    rnghide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    rngshow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
  Next
End Sub
```

It simply runs each sheet for the whole range and stores the rows to show/hide in seperate ranges and then change there status in one step (1 for show and 1 for hide for each sheet)

If you have any questions or get any errors just tell me (can't test it right now)

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
Sub t()
    Dim sheetArray() As Variant
    Dim ws&, finalRow&, startRow&
    Dim c As Range

    sheetArray = Array("Alabama", "North Carolina", "West Coast")
    For ws = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray)
        If sheetArray(ws) = "Main" Then
            startRow = 200
            finalRow = 500
        Else
            startRow = 50
            finalRow = 300
        End If
        For Each c In Sheets(sheetArray(ws)).Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & finalRow)
            If c.Value = 0 And Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                Sheets(sheetArray(ws)).Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
            Else
                Sheets(sheetArray(ws)).Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws    
End Sub
```

Just add to that array and it should work a little faster for you.  If you have a ton of sheets, and don't want to manually type them into the VBA code, you can always set the array to the range of sheet names, then just go from there. Let me know if you need help doing so.

This also assumes you don't want to just loop through the workbook. If so, you can just do `For each ws in ActiveWorkbook` instead of `lBound()...`

Edit: I added some code to check the sheet, so it'll correctly adjust your ranges.

Comment: `For Each c In Sheets("Main").Range("A200:A500")` see this in the question you have to implement a logic to see if that's Main` sheet or not and set for loop accordingly :) otherwise it will miss out on rows from 301 to 500 on that sheet.

Comment: bäm... while I was typing... and the start looks so much the same... (for the ranges part which is not avoidable to my eye)

Comment: application.screenupdating=false should also give significant improvements.  Also running the loop backwards (need to use a for loop instead of for each) is almost always faster when hiding or deleting rows.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each c In ws.Range(IIf(ws.Name = "Main", "A200:A500", "A50:A300"))
        ws.Rows(c.Row).Hidden = c.Value = 0
    Next
Next
```

if you want exclude sheet Raw,Main and Calendar :

```
Dim untreatedSheet As Variant
untreatedSheet = Array("Raw", "Main", "Calendar")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not (UBound(Filter(untreatedSheet, ws.Name)) > -1) Then
        For Each c In ws.Range("A50:A300")
            ws.Rows(c.Row).Hidden = c.Value = 0
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How do you know that's all the worksheets in the book? What if there are other sheets?

Comment: I don't know if this is even allowed `ws.Rows(c.Row).Hidden = c.Value = 0` ?

Comment: @findwindow@Abellah, that exactly what I was going to mention there are three other sheets that I don't want this to apply to named Raw, Main, and Calendar

Comment: @Luis see my last comment above to newguy ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you select all the sheets you want filtered FIRST:

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet

sAddress = "A:A"
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    ws.Range(sAddress).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
Next ws

End Sub
```